# Javascript generate many DOM elements with onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, onclick

I have the following script:

```
var div = document.getElementById("ShowAndHide");
var colbutton = document.createElement("a");
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Show/Hide column");
colbutton.appendChild(linkText);
colbutton.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0)");
jQuery.each(data.aoColumns, function(i, value){
    colbutton.onclick = function(){
        fnShowHide(i);
    }
div.appendChild(colbutton);
});

function fnShowHide( iCol ){
var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

Basically what I need is to create a number of DOM elements with sightly different attributes. 
I haven't found anything helpful so I decide to ask here.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you use jQuery? or rather not?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: You want to add your button `colbutton` multiple times?

Comment: That's right! but all of them should call the same function with different parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen that you're already use jQuery. So here is a jQuery solution:

```
var $div = $("#ShowAndHide");
var $colbutton = $("<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Show/Hide column</a>");

$.each(data.aoColumns, function(i) {
    $colbutton.clone()
        .on('click', fnShowHide.bind(window, i))
        .appendTo($div);
});

function fnShowHide( iCol ){
    var bVis = oTable.fnSettings().aoColumns[iCol].bVisible;
    oTable.fnSetColumnVis( iCol, bVis ? false : true );
}
```

Here is a working **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cfuvT/1/)**